# asp.net gridview control does not show paging numbers

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My asp.net site has master page. On one of the pages that use master page, I have 2 grid view controls. Both are tied to their own datasourcecontrols. I tried to enable paging on the grid but paging does not show up.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the PageSize property to something small, like 5, and see if it comes or not.

Also try setting the `AllowCustomPaging="true"` property.